# SQL pass variable to subquery

Tags: mysql, sql, database, subquery, query-variables

I can't pass variable to subquery.

I have 2 different tables where need get all interview persons.

Current my SQL

```
SELECT
   empl.id AS id,
   (SELECT
         GROUP_CONCAT(interviewed_by SEPARATOR ', ') 
      FROM
         (
            SELECT
               interview_old.interviewed_by 
            FROM
               interview_old 
            WHERE
               interview_old.empl = empl.id 

            UNION

            SELECT
               interview.interviewed_by 
            FROM
               interview
            WHERE
               interview.empl = empl.id 
         )
         as interviewed_by 
   ) AS interviews
FROM
   empl AS empl
```

It's not my full code, so **I can't change this part**

```
SELECT
   empl.id AS id,
   {only here allow insert custom sql}
FROM
   empl AS empl
```

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not 100% clear, but you can start by transforming your quesry to not use subquery but just `LEFT JOIN` with `GROUP`:

```
SELECT
   empl.id AS id,
   GROUP_CONCAT(i.interviewed_by SEPARATOR ', ')
FROM
   empl AS empl 
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT empl, interviewed_by
   FROM interview_old
   UNION
   SELECT empl, interviewed_by 
   FROM interview
) i
ON i.empl = empl.id 
GROUP BY empl.id
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get desired result from subquery and then join the whole thing with main table empl then you group by empid.

```
   SELECT
       empl.id AS id, GROUP_CONCAT(interviewed_by SEPARATOR ', ') 
        FROM
             (SELECT interview_old.empl employeeid, interview_old.interviewed_by as interviewed_by FROM interview_old
                    UNION
            SELECT  interview.empl,interview.interviewed_by 
                  FROM interview ) as tmp join   empl AS empl  on (empl.id=tmp.employeeid) 
                  group by  empl.id
```